# Split large file into small files with particular extension

Tags: linux

I want to split a large file into small files of 10000 lines each. I know I can do the same using:

```
split --lines=10000
```

However, the above command does not give extensions to the splitted files. I want to give all my split files the extension .txt Is it possible to do the same using split in linux. If yes, then how?

Also is it possible to number the files such that the first file has the name a1.txt. The second file has the name a2.txt, and so on. I know split gives names of the files as aa,ab, etc. but I want to replace this with a1.txt, a2.txt, a3.txt, a4.txt, a5.txt, a6.txt, a7.txt, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses the `-d` parameter, as:

```
split --lines=10000 -d <file>
```

Comment: To precisely answer the question, as written, you would want `split --lines=10000 --numeric-suffixes=1 <file>`.

Comment: Do I have to replace <file> by .txt

Comment: replease <file> for the file you wanto to split

Comment: Just a note: `-d` works for macOS, `--numeric-suffixes=1` do not.